# Am I using the following code to create a jquery slider, does the img change it but not the href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The slider only changes the path of src but not the link, where I have been wrong?

```
var imagenesSlider = $(".invisible > a");
var currentImg = 1;

setInterval(function() {
        console.log(imagenesSlider[currentImg])
        console.log(currentImg)
        $("#slider a").attr("href", $(imagenesSlider[currentImg]).find("a").attr("href"));
        $("#slider img").attr("src", $(imagenesSlider[currentImg]).find("img").attr("src"));
        currentImg++;
        if (currentImg == imagenesSlider.length) {
            currentImg = 0;
        }
    }, 6000)
```

Comment: Do multiple $(imagenesSlider[currentImg]).find("img") elements exist? attr only works on the first.

Comment: Please post the whole code along with HTML so we can help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update line

```
$("#slider a").attr("href", $(imagenesSlider[currentImg]).find("a").attr("href"));
```

to

```
$("#slider a").attr("href", $(imagenesSlider[currentImg]).attr("href"));
```

**Explanation:**

As **$(imagenesSlider[currentImg])** itself is **a** tag, you can directly get it's **href** attribute.

**find("a")** will try to search **a** tag in it's child elements and will never find it so it won't work!!

Comment: It's not a guess. It's totally clear that $(imagenesSlider[currentImg]) itself is a tag so it can't have a tag inside it!! so i removed find("a") from his code!!

Comment: That's exactly why it's worth describing why your solution works, not just dumping the code :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I added the explanation!